# Create table dynamically in jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

How to create dynamic rows for table in jade. My data for rows will be coming from MongoDB rendered by nodejs.
Here is my MongoDB document =>

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55429a92bf0adf38ce82052f"),
    "userid" : "103",
    "projectName" : "Nodejs Project",
    "startDate" : "03/15/2015",
    "endDate" : "05/15/2015",
    "tasks" : [ 
        {
            "taskid" : "5",
            "taskDescription" : "Task 5"
        }, 
        {
            "taskid" : "6",
            "taskDescription" : "Task 6"
        }, 
        {
            "taskid" : "7",
            "taskDescription" : "Task 7"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want taskDescription values to be disaplayed in rows.

Comment: [http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/#Javascript](http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/#Javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
table
  thead
    tr
      th Description
  tbody
    each task in tasks
      tr
        td=task.taskDescription
```

For future reference, you can test out your jade templates [here](http://jade-lang.com/demo/).